# Can't hightlight text with mouse in textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have some code inside `textarea` box.

I want users to copy the code inside the text area but it is not highlightable. I have tried everything and it is still not working.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```html
<textarea rows="3" cols="50">
  <button type="button" class="btn a-cart disabled"><span>ADD TO CART</span>
  </button>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the button from the text-area ? Put it just below it...

Comment: I just tried doing that and I am still not able to highlight the text. It's weird because I can do the act of highlighting the text and hitting copy/paste and it will work. Just the display of highlighting is not working.

Comment: I guess I might be a little confused by what you mean by "highlighting." Could you please edit your question and clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even your code seems to be working, it is better to encode your HTML

```html
<textarea rows="3" cols="50">
 &#x3C;button type=&#x22;button&#x22; class=&#x22;btn a-cart disabled&#x22;&#x3E;&#x3C;span&#x3E;ADD TO CART&#x3C;/span&#x3E;
  &#x3C;/button&#x3E;
</textarea>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eku52x9x/)

Comment: It works in your fiddle but not in my code. Would there be something in my CSS to not have it be able to be highlighted?

Comment: It's on a production server for my work that you need a password to view. Sorry. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: you can give at least the CSS in a fiddle?